# scrartcl - customizing the header

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I am writing a thesis using the scrartcl-class (see MWE below). There are three thing I do not achieve:

- If a new section starts, I do not want a headline or header-content to be shown. But it appears for the MWE below, even if it should not according to the documentation.
- Is it possible that the section names in the headline are in uppercase-letters, while the subsection names are exactly the way as they appear in the text? I can set `markcase=upper` or `markcase=noupper`, but is there a mixture of these?
- Can I increase the vertical whitespace before a new section starts? This command did not work `\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,afterskip=1.5,baselineskip,font=\LARGE]{section}`

Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,BCOR=20mm,DIV=12]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[autooneside=false,markcase=noupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\section{Introduction}
intro intro intro
\subsection{Introduction2}
intro2 intro2 intro2
\clearpage
\subsubsection{Chap2}
chap2 chap2 chap2
\clearpage
\subsection{chap3}
chap 3 chap3 chap3  
\clearpage
\section{Second Chapter}
\subsection{New subsec}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first and third point describe the behaviour of headings with `style=chapter`. 
`scrartcl` does not provide this sectioning style. So it is the wrong class for your first and third point. 
You have to switch to either `scrreprt` or `scrbook`, because they provide the sectioning command `\chapter`. `\chapter` executes `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` (depending on the settings of option `open`) automatically. Then you can also adjust the vertical space above the chapter title using `\RedeclareSectionCommand`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,BCOR=20mm,DIV=12,
  headings=normal% maybe you want this option, see the documentation
  ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\lehead{\MakeUppercase{\headmark}}
\rohead{\headmark}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext
\section{Introduction2}
\blindtext
\subsection{Section 2}
\Blindtext
\section{Section 3}
\Blindtext
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{New Section}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]